# How to show custom view created with merge tag in Android Studio preview window

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

When I have a layout which includes a custom view, how can I get the contents of my custom view to show up in the preview window in Android Studio?

I have a custom view based on LinearLayout:

```
class MyCustomView:LinearLayout {
        constructor(context:Context?):super(context)
        constructor(context:Context?, attrs:AttributeSet?):super(context, attrs) {
            initialize(context, attrs)
        }

        constructor(context:Context?, attrs:AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr:Int):super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
            initialize(context, attrs)
        }

        constructor(context:Context?, attrs:AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr:Int, defStyleRes:Int):super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) {
            initialize(context, attrs)
        }

        fun initialize(context:Context?, attrs:AttributeSet?) {
            LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_custom_view_layout, this)
        }
    }
```

It inflates a layout whose root is a `<merge/>` tag:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:parentTag="LinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/message_display"
    android:text="hello world"
    />
</merge>
```

I include the view as an element in my main layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_before"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="before"/>

        <com.my.app.MyCustomView
            android:id="@+id/custom_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_after"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="before"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I view my main layout in the preview window, the contents of my custom view are not visible.  I would like to be able to see my custom view, including the "hello world" TextField.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try rebuilding your project but I think that you need to add the other views programatically.

```
CustomLayout extends LinearLayout{
    public CustomLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);

        //Add your view to this layout
        this.add(new MyCustomFirstView());

        //Add other views the same way and customize LayoutParams here...
    }
}
```

I hope it helped :)

Answer (score -1):

Try it

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity { 


PopupWindow popUp;
boolean click = true;

LinearLayout mainLayout ;
Button btn ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    mainLayout =findViewById(R.id.activity_mainLinearLayout);
    btn = findViewById(R.id.main_btn);
    
    // code logic here
    popUp = new PopupWindow(this);
    final LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    ListView lin = new ListView(this);
    
    // Show window when text writing on editor
    btn.setOnClickListener(new 
            View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View p1) {
 if (click) {
                    
              popUp.showAtLocation(layout, 
         Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    
      popUp.update(50, 50, 380, 380);
                    
                    
                    click = false;
                } else {
                    popUp.dismiss();
                    click = true;
                }
                
            }
        });
    
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
   lin.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    ArrayAdapter adp = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[]{"ArrayList", "LinkedList","Random","new","This"});
   lin.setAdapter(adp);
   lin.setLayoutParams(params);
    layout.addView(lin, params);
    popUp.setContentView(layout);
      }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what the code does and how it solves the problem.